# no performance improvement with std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, audio, stdthread

I am working on a audio "real time" application and I would like to imrpove the performance of it. I actually already posted a topic but this is about std::thread specificly.

The audio processing ist mostly done by two seperate objects ( `leftProcessor` track and `rightProcessor`). Since these objects don't rely on each other, using two threads to process them should realy improve the performance with multi core CPUs. However, I currently get the opposite result.

Before I activated the compiler performance optimization (O2), using two threads got me about 50% more performance, but after I switched the optimization on, I got ~10-20% less performance, while the performance got drasticly better for both versions.

I measure the performance by taking the time at two points within the function and bruteforce printing the result to the screen so there could be some problems with this. ;)

My guess would be that creating a `std::thread` would take more time than I actually gain from running the processing on the second thread. 
In this case, is it possible to improve the performance by using the same "thread" for every function call and just passing the thread the new arguments? I don't realy know if this is possible.

The function currently takes about 0.0005ms to 0.002ms to process.

Here is the code:

```cpp
void AudioController::processAudio(int frameCount, float *output) {

#ifdef AUDIOCONTROLLER_MULTITHREADING
    // CALCULATE RIGHT TRACK
    std::thread rightProcessorThread;
    if(rightLoaded) {
        rightProcessorThread = std::thread(&AudioProcessor::tick,  //function
                                           rightProcessor,         //object
                                           rightFrameBuffer,       //arg1
                                           frameCount);            //arg2
    } else {
        for(int i = 0; i < frameCount; i++) {
            rightFrameBuffer[i].leftSample  = 0.0f;
            rightFrameBuffer[i].rightSample = 0.0f;
        }
    }

#else
    // CALCULATE RIGHT TRACK
    if(rightLoaded) {
        rightProcessor->tick(rightFrameBuffer, frameCount);     
    } else {
        for(int i = 0; i < frameCount; i++) {
            rightFrameBuffer[i].leftSample  = 0.0f;
            rightFrameBuffer[i].rightSample = 0.0f;
        }
    }

#endif

    // CALCULATE LEFT TRACK
    Frame * leftFrameBuffer = (Frame*) output;

    if(leftLoaded) {
        leftProcessor->tick(leftFrameBuffer, frameCount);       
    } else {
        for(int i = 0; i < frameCount; i++) {
            leftFrameBuffer[i].leftSample  = 0.0f;
            leftFrameBuffer[i].rightSample = 0.0f;
        }
    }

#ifdef AUDIOCONTROLLER_MULTITHREADING
    // CALCULATE RIGHT TRACK
    if(rightLoaded) {
        rightProcessorThread.join();
    }
#endif

    // MIX
    for(int i = 0; i < frameCount; i++ ) {
        leftFrameBuffer[i] = volume * (leftRightMix * leftFrameBuffer[i] + (1.0 - leftRightMix) * rightFrameBuffer[i]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Creating threads each time you need them cost a lot. Try to create them one time before your calls you should see some improvements.

Comment: The execution time of each function is really too short to gain anything from multithreading yet it is sufficient to do a meaningful benchmark. Your measurements could easily be skewed by a single cache miss.

Comment: So the results are to be expected? I wonder why I got an improvement when didn't had the compiler optimization on...